# Multiple COUNT in sql issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a little wired issue.
I have to select two count from query Likes and Collects but when I add second query instead of `2 likes and 10 collects` I get `10 likes and 10 collects`.
What am I doing wrong here?

```
select  COUNT(tl.ItemLikeId) as a, COUNT(tib.PacketId) as b
from Items i
left join ItemLikes il
on il.ItemId = i.ItemId
left join ItemsInPackets iip
on iip.ItemId = i.ItemId
where i.ItemId = 14591
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tl.ItemLikeId) AS a, COUNT(DISTINCT tib.PacketId) as b`.

Your join gives you ten rows, so you have ten IDs from each table.  However, not all of the IDs are unique.  You're looking for unique IDs.

Comment: Yes I see my error now. in ItemInPocket is N:N table. So I didn't add auto increment column. When I use distinct on those keys it works :)

Answer (score 2):

Count returns the number of rows.  Not the number of rows with a value, and not the number of distinct rows.

To get number row rows with a value

```
select  SUM(CASE WHEN tl.ItemLikeId IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as a, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN tib.PacketId IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as b
```

To get the number of distinct values, do what zimdanen suggested and use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`

```
select  COUNT(DISTINCT tl.ItemLikeId) as a, COUNT(DISTINCT tib.PacketId) as b
```

Another approach, if all you are using `ItemLikes` and `ItemsInPackets` for are the counts

```
select
    (
        SELECT COUNT(ItemLikeId) 
        FROM ItemLikes
        WHERE ItemId = i.ItemId
    ) as a,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(PacketId) 
        FROM ItemsInPackets
        WHERE ItemId = i.ItemId
    ) as b
from Items i
where i.ItemId = 14591
```

Comment: Actually, `COUNT(rowname)` will give you a count of rows that have a value for `rowname`.  `COUNT(1)` or `COUNT(*)` will give you a straight count of rows.

Comment: @zimdanen Good call. I was going on memory, but I checked and you are correct.